# Is it possible to use the Parse.com API with PHP on localhost?

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a backend architecture using PHP and Parse.com.  Is it possible to use the PHP API on localhost?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course is it possible. You have official [PHP api](https://parse.com/docs/php/guide) from parse.com,
also you can find  a complete list of [third party libraries](https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries). Also you have [REST api](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide) you can use !

Comment: I know but is there any way to use that api on LOCALHOST